# Is it possible to select multiple images in uipickerview

Tags: iphone, xcode, uiimagepickercontroller

I want to select multiple images from uipicker view , is it possible to get multiple images from UIImagepicker.What i know is that we can select one image t a time so how to select multiple images thanks.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2903004/multiple-row-selection-in-uipickerview

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I dont think that is possible using UIImagePickercontroller. If you want you take a look at this [multipleSelection](http://www.icodeblog.com/2010/10/07/cloning-uiimagepickercontroller-using-the-assets-library-framework/) as an alternative. It might be helpful.