# How to select multiple items in a dropdown box in iPhone?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I am an iPhone developer. I am trying to select multiple items in a dropdown box in iPhone. I have tried all possibilities but unable to do it. Please suggest me. It's really very important to me.

Thanks in advance.
fabre..

Comment: I think you should try using a tableView as te drop down and enable multiple selection. Here's a tutorial on that : http://briterideas.blogspot.ro/2012/07/uitableview-how-to-part-3-multiple.html

Comment: There's no specific drop down Component in ios. Use UITableView as your list. Maintain a image array for the selection of cells. Something like this.

http://www.theappcodeblog.com/images/Tutorial9/SimulatorShot1.png

Instead, use selected/unselected images for your tableview.

Comment: Dup of [Multiple Row Selection in UIPickerView](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2903004/)

Comment: This question is very poorly written. Read ["Writing the Perfect Question"](http://tinyurl.com/so-hints) for ways of improving it.

Answer (score 0):

Is there a dropdown box in iPhone? I am quiet sur that those doesn't exists and are usually replaced by tableView or picker.

What i would do is a tableview with self made cell views that are combining text and a 2 states button that design is a box checked or not depending on the button state. That should work fine with a proper controller behind.

Answer (score 0):

this is one of the best examples you are looking for

https://github.com/kiran5232/KDropDownMultipleSelection/archive/master.zip