# How you can select multiple items in dropdown box in iPhone and display in textboxs?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I am an iPhone developer. I am trying to select multiple items in a dropdown box in iPhone. I have tried all possibilities but unable to do it. Please suggest me. It's really very important to me. Please post your views as soon as possible.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: http://www.cocoacontrols.com/controls/alpickerview Please chek this url

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to select multiple items in a dropdown box in iPhone?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11448069/how-to-select-multiple-items-in-a-dropdown-box-in-iphone)

Comment: @Fabre: instead of posting a duplicate question, edit your original. However, before posting, search to make sure your question hasn't already been asked. SO uses a Q&A, rather than forum, format, and so works differently than many sites you're used to. Read the FAQs for more.

Comment: Sorry ..actually I had some problem with my proxy that day so was not sure whether it's posted or not so I asked again and thanks for your suggestions . I will make sure that this won't happen again . Thanks again ...

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming by dropdown box you mean the built in picker view that appears for some sort of a selection field. It would be nice if you posted what component are you exactly talking about. Regardless, based on the assumptions I can make on your question I think what you are looking for is this answer: [Multiple Row Selection in UIPickerView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2903004/multiple-row-selection-in-uipickerview).