# UIPickerview with Multiple selection supporting both orientation in iOS

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uipickerview

I want to implemenet a picker view in which user can select multiple rows and selected rows should show a "tick" mark.

After googling a lot i found [this](https://github.com/alexleutgoeb/ALPickerView) opensource code

But when i tried to support both orientation the GUI is showing in a improper manner.

Can anyone please help me for a picker view with multiple selection of rows supporting portrait and landscape orientation.

Hoping for your help.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How exactly does it behave and how does it differ from what you want to achieve?

Comment: Please refer to this link 
 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2903004/multiple-row-selection-in-uipickerview

Answer (score 1):

Add a image or empty pickerview and add a tableview in it and then 
and togggle the cell acessory type when select or deselect

```
cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark
```

Comment: @appdelegate thanks for your answer.i tried the way you suggested.but how to show picker.showsSelectionIndicator = YES;.when i add the table view above the picker it is hidding the selectionIndicator of picker view.can you please suggest a alternative..